# Jquery Ajax not hit Webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am using a local web service that is place in the root folder of the application.
I try to hit the service method using Jquery Ajax method then it  return 404 error. But the same code working fine on my local machine . This problem occur when test  it on the live server.  Is i need to do some setting in the web.config file ..Please guide me regarding this

Here is the Link of the web service :- http://solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx

- I am using MVC3

Thanks in Advance

here is the code :-

function BindPrices() {

```
    var derivative = $("#hdncderid").val();
    var Terms = "24";
    var Milage = "10000 mpa"

    Milage = $("#AnnualMilageList :selected").text();
    Terms = $("#drpterm :selected").val();

    var IsSpecial = 1
    var Type = "C"
    var IsMaintances = "0"

    var CtrServicePath = "http://solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: CtrServicePath,
        data: "{derivativeids:" + derivative + ", term: '" + Terms + "', milage: '" + Milage + "', IsSpecial: " + IsSpecial + ", typ: '" + Type + "', maintain: '" + IsMaintances + "'}",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; Characterset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data1) {

            var p = eval("(" + data1.d + ")");

            if (p.length > 0) {

                $.each(p, function (i, k) {

                    if (parseFloat(k.BusinessPrice1).toFixed(2) != 0.00 || k.BusinessPrice1 != 0.0) {

                        document.getElementById("SpnBussinessPrice").innerHTML = "£ " + parseFloat(k.BusinessPrice1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("SpnPersonalPrice").innerHTML = "£ " + parseFloat(k.PersonPrice1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("SpnPersonlInialsPrice").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsPersonalPayment1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("SpnBussinessInialsPrice").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsBusinessPayment1).toFixed(2);

                        document.getElementById("spnquotepayment").innerHTML = "£ " + parseFloat(k.BusinessPrice1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("spnquoteinitialpayment").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsBusinessPayment1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("spnquoteterm").innerHTML = Terms + " months";
                        document.getElementById("spnquotemilage").innerHTML = Milage.replace("mpa", "") + " miles";

                        document.getElementById("spnpermonthP").innerHTML = " per month";
                        document.getElementById("spnpermonthB").innerHTML = " per month";
                    }
                    else {


                        document.getElementById("SpnBussinessPrice").innerHTML = "Price on Request";
                        document.getElementById("SpnPersonalPrice").innerHTML = "Price on Request";
                        document.getElementById("spnpermonthP").innerHTML = "";
                        document.getElementById("spnpermonthB").innerHTML = "";

                        document.getElementById("SpnPersonlInialsPrice").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsPersonalPayment1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("SpnBussinessInialsPrice").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsBusinessPayment1).toFixed(2);

                        document.getElementById("spnquotepayment").innerHTML = "Price on Request";
                        document.getElementById("spnquoteinitialpayment").innerHTML = " £ " + parseFloat(k.IntialsBusinessPayment1).toFixed(2);
                        document.getElementById("spnquoteterm").innerHTML = Terms + " months";
                        document.getElementById("spnquotemilage").innerHTML = Milage.replace("mpa", "") + " miles";


                    }
                }
               );
            }
        },
        error: function (res) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to post your AJAX code, it is an URL formatting problem

Comment: If you find any answers helpful, please be sure to upvote and accept them. 0% is a little low.

Comment: Please dude, just copy paste your url into a new tab of your browser. You are not pointing on a valid URL => 404 http://solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx/GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID

Comment: but we can hit the service method like this. GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID is the name of the web method.

Comment: i think you must use relative url Or this link(please look "op" Query string):
http://solentcarleasing.co.uk/solentwebservice.asmx?op=GetLeasingPriceForTechinalPageByDerID

Answer (score 0):

Hey pardeep dhingra i think you are missing **'`;`'** at the **end of your vars**:

```
var derivative = $("#hdncderid").val();
var Terms = "24";
var Milage = "10000 mpa" // <------------------------------here

Milage = $("#AnnualMilageList :selected").text();
Terms = $("#drpterm :selected").val();

var IsSpecial = 1    // <----------------------------------here
var Type = "C"  // <---------------------------------------here
var IsMaintances = "0" // <--------------------------------here
```

Plz put **`;`** there and see if you get it work.

Thanks

Comment: see if this link helps you: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/making-your-web-services-available-to-the-world/1046325